# Tiny MCE clean up on load

Tags: tinymce

I had issue with the way tinymce generates when some content is pasted from MS Word .Tiny MCE has an option for paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true which fixed it for any new content.But I have some existing content in database which still is formatted with lot of generated unnecessary stuff. IS there any way to perform paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste function when tinymce is loaded ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can perform the cleanup action onInit (thats right after the initial content is loaded). This is the necessary setup configuration setting

```
setup : function(ed) {
   ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) {
       ed.execCommand('mceCleanup');
   });
},
```

Comment: Will this be same as cleanup that happens on pasting from MS word ?

Comment: yes and no, this cleanup gets called when something gets pasted into the editor, but the pasted content will get additionally handled depending on the tinymce configuration settings

Comment: it takes some time sometimes :)

Comment: this doesn't help me to get rid of the invalid elements during startup